# bold text when using 256 colors

Tags: terminal, colors, mutt

I am configuring colors in Mutt, but I think my problem is general to linux terminal.

For the 16 predefined colors (such as `red`) I can make it bold, by specifying `brightred`

However, when using 256 colors (such as `color208`), there is no such color as `brightcolor208`. I have following color theme in mutt:

```
color index color208 color236 ~T
```

How can I make the color208 bold (bright) ?

Comment: I didn't think there was a bold 208. There is just another color value (like 220) that appears to a bolder/brighter version of the first... See the [output of this script](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jasonwryan/4257255789/) for the 256 colour values.

Comment: my understanding is, `bold` is the same color, just the font is thicker (bold).

Comment: This depends entirely on how the terminal emulator renders bold. Even physical terminals dealt with bold in different ways (intensity and/or font changes).

Answer (score 8):

"Boldness" is set separately from "foreground color", but it is not supported by *Mutt*.  All you can do in *Mutt* is select a foreground and background color, no boldness.

In other cases, where it is possible to output arbitrary ANSI escape sequences, you would set a "bold color 208" as follows (you can execute that in any terminal that allows bold text to see the effect, *Gnome Terminal* works fine if you have it configured to display bold text):

```
echo this is NORMAL
echo '\e[1m' this is BOLD '\e[0m'
echo '\e[1;38;5;208m' this is BOLD 208 '\e[0m'
echo '\e[38;5;208m' this is NORMAL 208 '\e[0m'
```

(The SGR parameter "1" will turn on bold.  You send it with `<Esc>[1m`, and you can of course combine it with others, e.g. `<Esc>[1;5m` or as in the above example, where `38;5;x` selects a color from the XTerm 256-color space.)

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal must support 256-colors and have appropriate TERM environment variable set. You likely do not have 256-color support enabled.

For xterm:

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

For urxvt:

```
export TERM="urxvt-256color"
```

For tmux/screen:

```
export TERM="screen-256color"
```

I would place it in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` depending on situation.